# Jquery each and JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

I have a div that returns an array string:

```
<div class="overview"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','item_specs_json','""')%></div>
```

An array string that looks like this:

```
[{"k":"type","v":"blue"},{"k":"size","v":"large"}]
```

I am making a bulleted list from these and there are 25 instances of div.overview per page.
This works but only repeats the first item values for every div. I can't get this to loop each.
Is it possible to do this with what I have?

```
$(function () {
    var specs = $.parseJSON($(".overview").html());
    $("div.overview").html('<div class="bullet_spec"></div>');
    $.each(specs, function () {
        $('div.overview div').append('<ul class="specs"><li class="label">' + this.k + ' : ' + this.v + '</li></ul>');
    });
});
```

I've tried:

```
$('.overview').each(function () {
```

and this breaks the script.
Also FYI, when the script breaks the unique values appear on items correctly in the full array string format.

Comment: It works, http://jsfiddle.net/LsAXD/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got more than one "overview" element, then you'll have to iterate through that list.

```
$('.overview').each(function() {
  var $overview = $(this), specs = $.parseJSON($overview.html());
  $overview.html('<div class="bullet_spec"></div>');
  $.each(specs, function () {
    $overview.children('div').append('<ul class="specs"><li class="label">' + this.k + ' : ' + this.v + '</li></ul>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking *'I am making a bulleted list from these and there are 25 instances per page'* to mean there are 25 `.overview`, each with there own JSON. You *can* loop through each, mapping each JSON string to a collection of elements, appending the collection at the end:

```
$('.overview').each(function(){
   var theJSON = JSON.parse(this.innerHTML);
   $elems = $.map(theJSON, function(k,v){
     return $('<ul class="specs"><li class="label">' + k.k + ' : ' + k.v + '</li></ul>');
   });
   $spec = $('<div class="bullet_spec"></div>').append($elems);
   $(this).html($spec);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/cxQps/)